# How to list documents from table grouped by id?

Tags: postgresql, jinja2

I'm making a template to show documents by its parts (title, annotation, contenttext).

```
{% block header %}
    <h1>{% block title %}Documents{% endblock %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% for document in documents | groupby('documentid' %}
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-header">
            {{ document.annotation }}
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">{{ document.title}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">{{ document.contenttext }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The table looks like that:

```
documentid    title    annotation    contenttext
1             abc      abc           abc
1             abc      abc           def
2             zzz      xxx           yyy
3             ooo      mmm           fff
```

Two first rows have the same documentid so i want to display both 'abc' and 'def' in the same document. And then go frther.

Which construction will allow me to do that?

```
      title|annotation|contenttext
doc1: abc  |   abc    | abc def
doc2: zzz  |   xxx    | yyy
doc3: ooo  |   mmm    | fff
```

Comment: Use string_agg (or a similar agg function depending on your desired data type): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/48ficYwuZAfuBVtvs16sUo/0

Comment: @404, thanks a lot, that helped.